# I keep getting an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined" does anyone know what's wrong?

Tags: javascript

I use the following code in order to add an item to cart:

```
document.getElementsByName("commit")[0].click();
```

but then I get an error saying

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

I'm not really sure what the issue is because I used the same code for a different portion of my program, when I was clicking on process payment, and there was no error. Can anyone possibly help

Comment: it means that document.getElementsByName("commit")[0] doesn't return anything

Comment: Where is your code... Sample code... Or something...

Comment: Can you please post the related **HTML** as well? But as it's been mentioned, most probably there is no element with the name of `commit`.

Comment: Have you ever tried to run the code from the console (F12)? If this works, not in the page, then the DOM tree is probably not yet set up (the element does not yet exist). Then you have to either insert the Javascript behind the element in the page, or e.g. build a ready function with jQuery (`jQuery (function () {/ * my code * /});`

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps...

```js
document.getElementsByName('commit')[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('Call something what you want in here')
});

document.getElementsByName('commit')[0].click();
```

```html
<button name="commit">commit</button>
```

Comment: When I added this to my program                                                                                                  document.getElementsByName('commit')[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('Call something what you want in here')
    });                                                                                                                                              It just gave me the undefined error "addEventListener of undefined"

Comment: Add your javascript bottom of the HTML body tag, If no getElementByName getting undefined.

Comment: What do you mean by my javascript and HTML body tag

Comment: The document.getElementsByName('commit') should call after the DOM has completed. If not javascript getting error. So we need to add <script></script> tags after the <body> </body> element.

Answer (score 0):

Just a sample.

```js
document.querySelector('#prod-1230').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Add btn clicked. Calling Commit Btn');
  document.getElementsByName('commit')[0].click();
});
document.getElementsByName('commit')[0].addEventListener('click', () => console.log('Commit btn clicked.'));
```

```html
<button name="commit">Commit Btn</button>
<button id="prod-1230">Add To Cart</button>
```